# A term for this gesture (signs by hands) on the wall/screen

Tags: word-request

What do we call this?

[image: hand signs]

Hand signs on the wall? Hand gestures?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Shadow play*, *hand shadows*, or *shadow puppets* will all probably be understood, although when I hear "shadow puppets" [I usually think of things like this](http://www.liverpoolmuseums.org.uk/wml/things-to-see/javanese-shadow-puppet.aspx):

[image]

An older name for shadows thrown by hand is simply [hand shadows](http://www.abebooks.com/Hand-Shadows-Thrown-Wall-A-Series-Novel/17392136313/bd).  I've got this book, originally published in 1859, facing me on my bookshelf right now:

[image]

[You can see how the popularity of the terms has changed over time.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shadow%20play%2Cshadow%20puppet%2Chand%20shadow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000)

Comment: That book though! (+1) Wow.

Comment: From the US, and when I hear "shadow puppets" I only think of the hand puppets.

Answer (score 13):

It can be called [**hand(s) shadow puppet**](https://www.google.com.hk/?hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=hands+shadow+puppet).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[Shadow play](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shadow+play):

> - A play presented by casting shadows of puppets or actors on a screen. Also called shadowgraph, shadow show.

(AHD)

Answer (score 0):

Its just called `hand shadows`. If a story is told using that then its called `shadow play with hands`. A shadow play may consist of `hand shadows` and `shadow puppets`(shadow puppets are usually cut-out shapes of puppets).